# getting a specific item from json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

hello i have seen several questions like this on here, but none that i have found are of any use. ive been up all night trying to figure this out and i would really appreciate it if i had a strait answer. i am trying to get a specific thing from json output. in python i would know how to do this but i have no idea how to go about it in php. the json output is

```
{"sentences":[{"trans":"ã“ã‚“ã«ã¡ã¯","orig":"hello","translit":"Kon'nichiwa","src_translit":""}],"dict":[{"pos":"nom","terms":["ä»Šæ—¥ã¯"],"entry":[{"word":"ä»Šæ—¥ã¯","reverse_translation":["hello","good day"]}],"base_form":"hello","pos_enum":1}],"src":"en","spell":{"spell_html_res":"Hello!","spell_res":"Hello!","correction_type":[10],"related":1},"server_time":2}
```

what i am trying to get out of that is just the "trans" i know that you have to use something with foreach to do this. i have tried

```
$jsondata = json_decode($jsonstuff);
foreach($jsondata as $ret->sentences) {
$rets = $ret->trans;}
print $rets;
```

however this does nothing. if somebody could please help it would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP doesn't know the syntax for a `foreach` loop, which to explain is clearly out of scope for a site for enthusiast and professional programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$jsondata = json_decode($jsonstuff);
foreach($jsondata->sentences as $ret) {
    $rets = $ret->trans;
    print $rets;
}
```

Comment: This code looks weird

Comment: oh wow i cant believe i missed that.

Comment: but thanks. solved the problem

Comment: Btw I frequently find trouble somewhere down the road when using variable names like that (eg $ret and $rets). I should know because I'm chronically bad at naming variables, functions, and classes.

Answer (score 1):

In this type of situation it might be helpful to have json_decode return you an array rather than a php object.  You can do this by adding the optional 2nd parameter.

Since sentences in your example is an array, you can see that at least with this input, you can easily get to the trans element by referencing element 0 of the array.

```
$jsondata = json_decode($jsonstuff, true);

echo $jsondata['sentences'][0]['trans'];

// See full array
var_dump($jsondata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must format your foreach code

`foreach($jsondata->sentences as $ret) {` instend of

```
foreach($jsondata as $ret->sentences) {
```

Formated code

```
$jsondata = json_decode($jsonstuff);
foreach($jsondata->sentences as $ret) {
    $rets = $ret->trans;
    print $rets;
}
```